# Node.JS string match only first character

Tags: node.js, regex

How can I check in regex or with different function that in the text first character contains one of these characters `,._-;<>?!` ?

I have this code for `,.;_-`

```
string.match(/[^,.;a-zA-Z0-9_-]|[,;._-]$/igm)
```

It works, but it check in whole sentences. I want only check the first character. I know, there is `IndexOf`, but I can't use regex in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the other way around. Keep a string of the characters you want to look for, and use the first character of your string to match against those characters.

```
const characters = ',._-;<>?!'

let myString = '...'
if (characters.includes(myString.charAt(0))) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Lol, so easy was. :o Thank you very much. :)